Nestjs graphql argument dto is empty
Let's say that I have 2 dtos:
export class RegisterDto {
  @Field()
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Fullname is required' })
  @IsString({ message: 'Fullname must be a string' })
  fullname: string;

  @Field()
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Password is required' })
  @MinLength(8, { message: 'Fullname must be a string' })
  password: string;

  // @Field()
  // @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Confirm Password is required' })
  // confirmPassword: string;

  @Field()
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Email is required' })
  @IsEmail({}, { message: 'Fullname must be a string' })
  email: string;
}

export class LoginDto {
  @Field()
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Email is required' })
  @IsEmail({}, { message: 'Email must be valid' })
  email: string;

  @Field()
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Email is required' })
  password: string;
}

the loginDto works fine in the loging resolver since the data gets filled in the argument.
  @Mutation(() => User)
  async login(
    @Args('loginInput') loginDto: LoginDto,
    @Context() context: { req: Request; res: Response },
  ) {
    return this.authService.login(loginDto, context.res); 
  }

However, the issue comes with the registerDto, the data is not being passed to the mutation arguments:
  @Mutation(() => User)
  async register(
    @Args('registerDto') registerDto: RegisterDto,
    @Context() context: { req: Request; res: Response },
  ) {
    const { user } = await this.authService.register(registerDto, context.res);
    return { user };
  }

This is the traceback call when executing this mutation:
mutation {
  register(registerDto:{email:"asd",fullname:"asd",password:"asd"}){
    fullname
  }
}

The error thrown by graphql:
"originalError": {
          "message": [
            "Fullname must be a string",
            "Fullname must be a string"
          ],
          "error": "Bad Request",
          "statusCode": 400
        }

Does anyone has experience a similar issue?

3 types of your error return Fullname must be a string, you receive 2 Fullname must be a string should be cause by asd is not an email and  asd not meet min length 8 constraint

Thanks much. So dumb from me, I was coding at late night and didn't keep an eye to the validations

You have decorated your email and password with message : "Fullname must be a string" and since you don't enter valid email and password you are getting error
